# Scaling NOAA CDR AVHRR NDVI imagery with image.reduceRegion()?

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
var reduce = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), geom);
```

Using this code above on AVHRR NDVI imagery (with a resolution of 0.05 arc degrees), what scale should I set reduceRegion to? Scale accepts input of meters, but the resolution of this dataset is in arc degrees. Link to AVHRR NDVI metadata below:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_CDR_AVHRR_NDVI_V4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reduction will by default use the scale of the viewer.  However, you can check the scale of the imagery with the following code, and add it to the `scale` parameter of `reduceRegion`

```
print (img.projection().nominalScale())
```